# Grammatical cases occurring only in conlangs

Tags: unnatural-features, case

What are examples of grammatical cases that are not attested in natural languages, but occur in some conlang?

To qualify here, the conlang should have at least some bit of flesh (e.g., a few consistent texts, either original or translated). Pure sketches of potential cases aren't interesting to me.

The [Respective or Dedative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Respective_case) case in Quenya, also called [Short Locative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quenya_grammar#Noun_declension), is too speculative to be counted here; its attestation is very weak in the available material from J. R. R. Tolkien.

Comment: Hmm/ It should be noted that you contradict your own stipulation of "pure sketches of potential cases aren't interesting to me". A mere mention in one letter does not some bit of flesh make. I would respectfully suggest you edit: either allow sketches and mere mentions or else delete the Tolkien reference. Or better yet, use the Tolkien reference as an example of what you are **nòt** looking for.

Comment: Reading through the available material on the Short Locative, any assignment of meaning to it is highly speculative. I change the wording of my question accordingly.

Comment: Looks better I think!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the best conlang to look for such cases is Ithkuil. http://ithkuil.net/04_case.html contains a list of all cases. My [short] research suggests that some of them (e.g. navigative for "noun relative to whose vector, arc, or trajectory of motion an event takes place" or allapsive for "amount of time that expected to pass between the contextual present and the time of a future event") aren't attested in any other well-known language. I may be wrong, but it seems plausible regarding Ithkuil's goal of expressing extensive detail.

Comment: O wow ... 72 cases, there must be a lot of innovations there! +1

Comment: if you go through them, it turns out that they all make logical sense, and they are all infuriatingly pedantic in their distinctions.